# EF Core Specification pattern add all column for sorting data with custom specification

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, specification-pattern

I applied **Specification Pattern** for my .net core project.
I also created custom specification for Include, Sorting, Paging etc.

I get `sort` value from api url with queryString and passing to custom specification class.
In this class i added some `switch case` for determine which column should `orderBy` or `orderByDescending`

But there is too much columns in that table. So is there any way to apply that `sort` variable to all column at once ? or do i have to write all columns in to the `switch` ?

here is my custom specification class.

```
public class PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges : BaseSpecification<Person>
{
public PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges(string sort) : base()
{
    AddInclude(x => x.Group);
    AddInclude(x => x.Privilege);
    
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
    {
        switch (sort)
        {
            case "gender": ApplyOrderBy(x => x.Gender); break;
            case "genderDesc": ApplyOrderByDescending(x => x.Gender); break;
            case "roomNo": ApplyOrderBy(x => x.RoomNo); break;
            case "roomNoDesc": ApplyOrderByDescending(x => x.RoomNo); break;
            default: ApplyOrderBy(x => x.Name); break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**ISpecification.cs Interface**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace XXXX.Core.Specifications
{
    public interface ISpecification<T>
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> Criteria { get; }
        List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Includes { get; }
        List<string> IncludeStrings { get; }
        Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderBy { get; }
        Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderByDescending { get; }
        Expression<Func<T, object>> GroupBy { get; }

        int Take { get; }
        int Skip { get; }
        bool IsPagingEnabled { get; }
    }
}
```

**BaseSpecification.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace XXXX.Core.Specifications
{
    public abstract class BaseSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
    {
    protected BaseSpecification(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
    {
        Criteria = criteria;
    }
    protected BaseSpecification()
    {

    }
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Criteria { get; }
    public List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Includes { get; } = new List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>();
    public List<string> IncludeStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderBy { get; private set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderByDescending { get; private set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> GroupBy { get; private set; }

    public int Take { get; private set; }
    public int Skip { get; private set; }
    public bool IsPagingEnabled { get; private set; } = false;

    protected virtual void AddInclude(Expression<Func<T, object>> includeExpression)
    {
        Includes.Add(includeExpression);
    }

    protected virtual void AddInclude(string includeString)
    {
        IncludeStrings.Add(includeString);
    }

    protected virtual void ApplyPaging(int skip, int take)
    {
        Skip = skip;
        Take = take;
        IsPagingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected virtual void ApplyOrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpression)
    {
        OrderBy = orderByExpression;
    }

    protected virtual void ApplyOrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDescendingExpression)
    {
        OrderByDescending = orderByDescendingExpression;
    }

    protected virtual void ApplyGroupBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> groupByExpression)
    {
        GroupBy = groupByExpression;
    }
    }
}
```

**SpecificationEvaluator.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using DesTech.Core.Entities;
using DesTech.Core.Specifications;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace XXXX.Infrastructure.Data
{
public class SpecificationEvaluator<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> inputQuery, ISpecification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        var query = inputQuery;

    if (specification.Criteria != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(specification.Criteria);
    }

    query = specification.Includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

    query = specification.IncludeStrings.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

    if (specification.OrderBy != null)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(specification.OrderBy);
    }
    else if (specification.OrderByDescending != null)
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(specification.OrderByDescending);
    }

    if (specification.GroupBy != null)
    {
        query = query.GroupBy(specification.GroupBy).SelectMany(x => x);
    }
    if (specification.IsPagingEnabled)
    {
        query = query.Skip(specification.Skip)
                     .Take(specification.Take);
    }
    return query;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Where can we see the base specification class code?

Comment: @IvanStoev I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use Reflection to get the property by name and then build the `Expression<Func<PersonWithGroupsAndPrivileges, object>>` expression.

Let's assume a specification class like this:

```cs
public class BaseSpecification<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderBy { get; private set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderByDescending { get; private set; }
    
    protected virtual void ApplyOrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpression)
        => OrderBy = orderByExpression;

    protected virtual void ApplyOrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDescendingExpression)
        => OrderByDescending = orderByDescendingExpression;
}
```

Here is a fully working sample console project, that implements a `PersonWithGroupsAndPrivileges<T>` class and uses it on a `Person` class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string RoomNo { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseSpecification<T>
    {
        public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderBy { get; private set; }
        public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderByDescending { get; private set; }
        
        protected virtual void ApplyOrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpression)
            => OrderBy = orderByExpression;

        protected virtual void ApplyOrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDescendingExpression)
            => OrderByDescending = orderByDescendingExpression;

        protected void ApplySorting(string sort)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
            {
                const string descendingSuffix = "Desc";

                var descending = sort.EndsWith(descendingSuffix, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var propertyName = sort.Substring(0, 1).ToUpperInvariant() +
                                   sort.Substring(1, sort.Length - 1 - (descending ? descendingSuffix.Length : 0));

                var specificationType = GetType().BaseType;
                var targetType = specificationType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                var property = targetType.GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName) ??
                               throw new InvalidOperationException($"Because the property {propertyName} does not exist it cannot be sorted.");

                // Create an Expression<Func<T, object>>.
                var lambdaParamX = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "x");

                var propertyReturningExpression = Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Convert(
                        Expression.Property(lambdaParamX, property),
                        typeof(object)),
                    lambdaParamX);

                if (descending)
                {
                    specificationType.GetMethod(
                            nameof(ApplyOrderByDescending),
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Invoke(this, new object[]{propertyReturningExpression});
                }
                else
                {
                    specificationType.GetMethod(
                            nameof(ApplyOrderBy),
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Invoke(this, new object[]{propertyReturningExpression});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges<T> : BaseSpecification<T>
    {
        public PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges(string sort)
        {
            ApplySorting(sort);
        }
    }
    
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var p1 = new PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges<Person>("gender");
            var p2 = new PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges<Person>("genderDesc");
        }
    }
}
```

The code works with any class `T`.

Comment: thank you for answer. when run this line every time its throw exception even sort name is in column `var property = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Because the property {propertyName} does not exist it cannot be sorted.");` and **getting internal server error with status code 500**

Comment: getting **property** always null @lauxjpn

Comment: Are the properties you want to sort on the `PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges` class itself or on another class?

Comment: I updates my answer to work with any Type `T` and included a fully working sample project.

Comment: Its another class with name **Person** I edited question you can see * PersonsWithGroupsAndPrivileges* getting from **Person**  @lauxjpn

Answer (score 2):

You basically need two helper methods - one which extracts sort information (name and descending) from sort string, and another which builds dynamically and applies  `Expression<Func<T, object>>` from it. Both go to the base generic class.

The first which handles patterns like `{property}[[ ]{Desc}]` (case insensitive) could be like this:

```cs
protected virtual void ExtractSortInfo(string sort, out string propertyPath, out bool descending)
{
    const string Desc = "Desc";
    propertyPath = sort;
    descending = false;
    if (propertyPath.EndsWith(Desc, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        propertyPath = sort.Substring(0, sort.Length - Desc.Length).TrimEnd();
        descending = true;
    }
}
```

and the second like this:

```cs
public virtual void ApplySort(string sort)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort)) return;
    ExtractSortInfo(sort, out var propertyPath, out var descending);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var body = propertyPath.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
    if (body.Type.IsValueType) body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
    if (descending)
        ApplyOrderByDescending(selector);
    else
        ApplyOrderBy(selector);
}
```

As an extra, this supports dot separated nested properties like `blog.name` for class `Person` having navigation property `Blog` having property `Name`.

`Expression.Convert` is for supporting value type (`int`, `decimal`, `DateTime` etc.)  properties